# MySQL I can not write data into the database

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys i have problem with inserting data in mysql database.I accepted a project that my friend worked.

I make simple php test file and try to insert in table `_content_city`. query is successfully executed bu no records in database column when i check in phpmyadmin.

```
$handler = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);
$database = mysql_select_db($dbname);

if(!$handler) :
    die("Faild connect to MySQL :" . mysql_error());
endif;

if(!$database) :
   die("DB with name ". $dbname . " no exists " . mysql_error());
endif;

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO _content_grad (wishlist) VALUES('BlaBlaBla') ") or die(mysql_error());  

 printf ("Inserterd records: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
```

When i execute this code in browser i have message **Inserterd records: 1** 
 But when i check in phpmyadmin that data no exist in column. I dont know whay.

You guys can see image and u will see column **`wishlist`** is empty.

http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/1852/5hfw.png

I check foreign_keys and remove all foreign_keys and again dont work.

Like test i make new database with name **new_test_base** and make table **albums** and column **title** and like test i execute my php code and all data is successfully inserted when i check in phpmyadmin. So problem is only in that database, i have full access and privilegies i use **root (ALL)**

Any solution to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php ... I will not answer old depreciated php_mysql questions

Comment: Do your server logs show any errors?

Comment: What type and limit wishlist col?

Comment: Your screenshot shows **existing** records, not new records. You'll see you have empty records, with **only** wishlist set.

Comment: check you php version first.You can't use mysql_* after PHP 5.5.0

Comment: @I'm working on an existing project and can not be changed. Errors is empty i check now. that col is varchar 225

Comment: My php version is 5.4.4-9 am doing on localhost

Comment: Try the query `INSERT INTO _content_grad (wishlist) VALUES('BlaBlaBla')` in phpMyAdmin

Comment: I execute query **INSERT INTO _content_grad (wishlist) VALUES('BlaBlaBla')** in my phpadmin and is successfuly i get message ** 1 row inserted. ** ** Inserted row id: 3230 ( Query took 0.0161 sec ) ** but that data no exist when i check col

Comment: I try server where is website stored but dont work again

Comment: @Jony try again with an empty table.

Comment: OK i fix my problem. Problem be in phpmyadmin. I install mysql webkich and when add new data in wishlist col i see all in mysql webkich after refresh. So i must reinstal phpmyadmin probobly is bugged or somthing else. Tnx guys for helps.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL_* range of functions have been depreciated and are no longer reccomened for use. Use the MySQLi_* range of functions instead.

In your code, put the following line `echo mysql_errno($handler)` and it should display the latest error retuned by MySQL, a MySQLi version of this function is also available.

Comment: Bro i cant use Mysql bcs people who develop that use own DB class (MySQL) and I am limited to doing only mysql. I know new version is better mysqli and i know to work in mysqli but in this case i cant. when i put parametar $handler in mysql_error and execute he back me again "Inserted records 1 "

Comment: Now i try in my test.php to use **mysqli** and execute scuccessifuly but again no data in phpmyadmin

Comment: Have you added the line of code I suggested? MySQL -  echo mysql_error($handle); MySQLi - echo mysqli_error($handle);

Comment: Yes i add and replay for that. he return some message **Inserted records 1**